# Section name in PDF reader side bar

Tags: pdf, section-titles

i have a problem with the section names in the PDF reader side bar. I'm using the hyperref package. Inside my appendix I'm adding sections this way (MWE):

```
\documentclass[12pt,
                a4paper,
                onside,
                listof=flat]{report}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch:1}
\section{Section}\label{ch1:section}

\chapter*{A Appendix}
\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{A}\makeatother
\label{ch:appendix}
\markboth{CHAPTER A APPENDIX}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A Appendix}

\section*{A.4 Software Design}
\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{A.4}\makeatother
\label{ch:appendix:sec:4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\makebox[0.9cm][l]{A.4}Software Design}

\end{document}
```

I chose this "definition" to have the sections numbered as A.1, A.2.... and also have the correct section name in the table of content with the fitting spacing between the "number" A.4 and the name "Software Design" as well as the correct "number" when using \ref{ch:appendix:sec:4}. When I now generate a PDF, the section is displayed in the side bar as "[0.9cm][l]A.4Software Design" and not as "A.4 Software Design" (see picture).

[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix this, without destroing the rest of the definition? Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. Im not an latex ecpert so please apologies if this definition is "ugly"

Comment: Do not show only code snippets. Always show a small but complete example. That makes it much easer to test your issue.

Comment: Dear Ulrike, thank you for your hint. I edited my question and included a MWE.